# Python - Assign value based on condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a variable that stores email address. Based on the email address assigned to this variable I would like to assign a new email address to another variable.

Given below is some info on this.

```
var1 <- Variable can have one of the two values as mentioned below:


 1. apple@mail.com
 2. tomato@mail.com
```

I am trying to create a new variable called `var2` which will have **fruit@mail.com** if `var1 = apple@mail.com` or have **veg@mail.com** if `var1 = tomato@mail.com`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can you `list`. use the `append`

Comment: For `python` version  > 3.8 there's walrus operator. I think that could work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a dict for larger mappings

```
mappings = {
     'apple@gmail.com': 'fruit@gmail.com', 
     'tomato@gmail.com': 'veg@gmail.com' 
}
```

Or define them (dyamically) one-by-one:

```
mappings['apple@gmail.com'] = 'fruit@gmail.com'
mappings['tomato@gmail.com'] = 'veg@gmail.com'
# ....
```

Later it's easy to use/extend:

```
var2 = mappings['apple@gmail.com']
```

at this point var2 will contain "fruit@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with simple `if-else` statement. For example:

```
mail_list = []
def assign_email(var1):
  if var1 == 'apple@mail.com':
      var2 = 'fruit@mail.com'
  elif var1 = 'tomato@mail.com':
      var2 = 'veg@mail.com'
  else
      var2 = 'default@mail.com'
  return var2

def add_mail_tolist(var1):
    var2 = assign_email(var1)
    mail_list.append(var2)
```

Funtion will return var2 as a `string`, if you like you can add it to let's say mail `list` with `append` function.

So you just need to call `def add_mail_tolist(var1)` with an argument `var1`, then based on the vlaue of `var1`, `var2` will be added to the `mail_list`. Then you can access your email with `index`

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options here. with option 1 as the following

```
var1 = 'apple@gmail.com'
if var1 == 'apple@gmail.com':
    var2 = 'fruit@gmail.com'
elif var1 == 'tomato@gmail.com':
    var2 = 'veg@gmail.com'

print(var2)
```

Alternatively you could use Python's ternary operator. Note that this does not check for 'tomato', it simply assigns "veg@gmail.com" whenever "apple@gmail.com" is not found.

```
var1 = 'apple@gmail.com'
var2 = 'fruit@gmail.com' if var1 == 'apple@gmail.com' else 'veg@gmail.com'

print(var2)
```